# SharePoint REST get column LikedBy with method GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl to library

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-library, angularjs

I created a library with images, there are many folders and into folder there are one or many images.
I need get the likes(rating) of the image by current user.

Please help me to find the likedby in SharePoint 2016 rest api (Document Library).

```
        galleryService.getAll()
                .done(function (response) {

                    $scope.galleryimages = [];


                    var resultfolder = response.data.d.results;

                    angular.forEach(resultfolder, function (valuefolder, key) {
                        galleryService.getImagesByFolder(valuefolder.Title).done(function (response) {

                            angular.forEach(response.data.d.results, function (valueimage, key) {                                   


                                 ¿¿¿ LikedBy ????

                                var image = {
                                    Id: valueimage.ListItemAllFields.ID,
                                    Title: valuecarpeta.Title,
                                    FileRef: valuecarpeta.FileRef

                                };
                                $scope.galleryimages.push(image);

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
```

////Query rest api

method: getImagesByFolder

var query = "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('galleryimages/" + folderName + "')/files?" +
        "$select=Name,ServerRelativeUrl&$top=1&$orderby=Name%20asc";

Answer (score 5):

You could consider the following options

**Option 1.**

1) modify the query to include additional information. Since *Ratings* properties belong to `ListItem` resource, append the following expression: `$expand=ListItemAllFields` to the endpoint url

2) once the data is returned perform the filtering by *on the client side* by Ratings field

Example:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/contoso/documents')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields";

$.getJSON(url)
.then(function(data){
     var result =  data.value.filter(function(item){
         if(item.ListItemAllFields.LikedByStringId.indexOf(_spPageContextInfo.userId.toString()) >= 0)
            return item;
     }); 

     console.log(result.length);
});
```

**Option 2.**

Replace the endpoint `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<url>')/files` with `GetItems` method:

```
Url:/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<listTitle>')/GetItems?$expand=File
Method: POST
Data:  {
  "query": {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "SP.CamlQuery"
    },
    "ViewXml": "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"LikedBy\" LookupId=\"TRUE\"/><Value Type=\"UserMulti\">17</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>",
    "FolderServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/contoso/Documents/Archive"
  }
}

Headers:
     X-RequestDigest: <request digest>
     Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
     Content-Type : "application/json; odata=verbose"
```

Advantages:

- filtering by Ratings field is perform *on the server side*
- file along with associated list items could be retrieved via a single
  request

Example

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/GetItems?$expand=File";
var query = "<View>" +
              "<Query>" +
                  "<Where>" +
                      "<Eq>" +
                         "<FieldRef Name=\"LikedBy\" LookupId=\"TRUE\"/>" +
                         "<Value Type=\"UserMulti\">" +
                              _spPageContextInfo.userId +
                         "</Value>" +
                       "</Eq>" +
                   "</Where>" +
               "</Query>" +
           "</View>";


var folderUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Documents/Archive";

var queryPayload = { "query" :
           {
               "__metadata": { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" },
               "ViewXml": query,
               "FolderServerRelativeUrl": folderUrl 
           }
        };


executePost(url,queryPayload)
.then(function(data){
    var items = data.d.results;
    items.forEach(function(item){
       //console.log(item.LikesCount); //Likes count
       //console.log(item.LikedByStringId); //user ids
       console.log(item.File.Name); //File properties like Name    
    });

})
```

where

```
function executePost(url,payload){
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, for this solution. I used the solution Option 2. It worked for me

Comment: I'm trying option 2 and I am able to filter on the LikedBy and I get the LikesCount, but neither the LikedBy nor the LikedByStringId are included in my results. Any ideas?

Comment: So I tried option 1 and again I get the ListItemAllFields, but don't get LikeBy or LikedByStringId.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following line of code to get the item information(include LikedBy).

```
var query = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('galleryimages')/Items?$filter=substringof('/"+folderName+"/',FileRef)&$select=ID,FileLeafRef,Title,FileRef,LikesCount,LikedBy/Title&$top=1&$orderby=FileLeafRef asc&$expand=LikedBy";
```

Comment: thank you for you answer me, but the query doesn't return anything. :(

filter=substringof('/"+folderName+"/',FileRef) not working, if I remove this one (filter) return records fine.

Comment: Check whether the value of folderName variable is right or not.

Comment: the value is correct, I changed way to consume data, I maked by CSOM. Thank you

Comment: Yes, we can use JSOM to achieve it.