# SP Online rest api: How to get all properties/columns from folders within another folder in a single request?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, folder

I have the "Goods" folder which I can access with the following endpoint:

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/***/Goods/')
```

If I expand the above folder with Folders, I can get a list of all the folders within "Goods":

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/***/Goods/')?$expand=Folders
```

However, the above endpoint has no properties. For example. Each folder inside Goods has a "Status" column that is missing in the response I get. I don't want to iterate over each folder to get the value of the Status column.

Is there a way to get all properties from the folders inside "Goods" in a single request?

I have tried using expand and select, but it didn't work as expected. What am I missing?

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/***/Goods/')?$expand=Folders&$select=Folders/ID,Folders/Status,Folders/Step
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `ListItemAllFields` to `$expand` to get additional details from folders like:

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/***/Goods/')/folders?$expand=Folders,ListItemAllFields
```

OR (update from comments):

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/***/Goods/')/folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint REST get column LikedBy with method GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl to library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226658/sharepoint-rest-get-column-likedby-with-method-getfolderbyserverrelativeurl-to-l)

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick reply. The code in the reference you mentioned made me realize I wanted the folders within GOODS, so I needed "/folders in my url.
Then expanding with ?$expand=ListItemAllFields did the trick!
I leave the full url to help people who may stumble upon this post:
https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/***/Goods/')/folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I have updated my answer accordingly.