# how to retrieve lookup fields from files

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column

I am trying to expand the following lookup fields, but I am finding it hard:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Acts/Shared Documents/2022_1')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

---

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "http://sp2019/sites/Acts/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Files12",
  "value": [
    {
      "odata.type": "SP.File",
      "odata.id": "http://sp2019/sites/Acts/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/Acts/Shared%20Documents/2022_1/Document.docx')",
      "odata.editLink": "Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/Acts/Shared%20Documents/2022_1/Document.docx')",
      "ListItemAllFields@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/Acts/Shared%20Documents/2022_1/Document.docx')/ListItemAllFields",
      "ListItemAllFields": {
        "odata.type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem",
        "odata.id": "4dedfc0e-49dd-409d-813a-b0d6b286be98",
        "odata.etag": "\"4\"",
        "odata.editLink": "Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/Acts/Shared%20Documents/2022_1/Document.docx')/ListItemAllFields",
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 8,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ComplianceAssetId": null,
        "Title": null,
        "**RelatedContactId**": 1,
        "**RelatedCauseId**": 1,
        "**DocsTypologyId**": 3,
        "ID": 8,
      },
      "CheckInComment": "",
      "CheckOutType": 2,
      "CustomizedPageStatus": 0,
      "ETag": "\"{0E9B67EA-F00C-4065-B956-C9C4B2EEB2EC},6\"",
      "Exists": true,
      "Name": "Document.docx",
      "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/Acts/Shared Documents/2022_1/Document.docx",
      "Title": "",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to expand "RelatedCauseId", and some other lookup fields.

tried a lot of things, but no luck. These are just two of them:

```
/Files?$select=RelatedCase/Title&$expand=ListItemAllFields,ListItemAllFields/RelatedCause
/Files?$select=RelatedCause/Title&$expand=ListItemAllFields,RelatedCause

?$expand=Files,Folders,ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields
```

Comment: Try Option 2 given using "GetItems" method at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226658/sharepoint-rest-get-column-likedby-with-method-getfolderbyserverrelativeurl-to-l. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I am looking how to expand lookup fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your expand to `$expand=ListItemAllFields,ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText`

Doing so will get you both the lookup Ids (as part of ListItemAllFields) and the lookup values (as part of FieldValuesAsText).

**Update:**

As per your comment, I was incorrect with my answer above. The lookup field Ids were included with item version data, not the item data itself. I id some further testing and came up with the following solution. It's similar to the one proposed in the answer given by Ganesh.

Include the lookup Id in the select clause of the query string. Doing so should get you both the lookup Id (as part of ListItemAllFields) and the lookup value (as part of FieldValuesAsText).

`$select=ListItemAllFields/FileLeafRef,ListItemAllFields/RelatedCauseId&$expand=ListItemAllFields,ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText`

I tested this and I am getting back both the lookup Id and the lookup value.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but now I lost the IDs.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I saw the ID in the response but it's part of the version data, not the item data. Let me see if I can come up with another option.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to answer given by @Rob Windsor above, you can get both lookup column ID and values using endpoint in below format:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Acts/Shared Documents/2022_1')/Files?$select=*,ListItemAllFields/RelatedCauseId&$expand=ListItemAllFields,ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText
```

**Documentation**: [Working with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

---

**Update from comments**:

For me, it returns lookup item ID in property like `ParentLookupId`:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:ParentLookupId m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ParentLookupId>
</m:properties>
```

[image]

Comment: it does not show the IDs either

Comment: For me, it returns lookup item ID. check updated answer.